# REGEX to identify only plain text

Tags: regex, vba

I am working in VBA and have a regex to identify a pattern ASA1234ss.
I am converting certain pattern of item in inbox to urls.

```
Body=objItem.HTMLBody
With RegX
        .Pattern = "ASA[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z]"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = Not MatchCase
End With
        'Replacing the pattern with a hyperlink
Body = RegX.Replace(Body, "<a href='http://www.stack.com=$&'>$&</a>")
objItem.HTMLBody = Body
```

This works good in replacing the pattern only once. But when I again execute the macro, the hyperlinked patterns again gets replaced with same text appending to it.

For Eg:

Sample Input

```
ASA8765jd
ASA7765jh
ASA8873hi
```

First Execution

```
<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8765jd'>ASA8765jd</a>
<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA7765jh'>ASA7765jh</a>
<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8873hi'>ASA8873hi</a>
```

Second Execution

```
<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8765jd'>ASA8765jd</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8765jd'>ASA8765jd</a></a>
<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA7765jh'>ASA7765jh</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA7765jh'>ASA7765jh</a></a>
<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8873hi'>ASA8873hi</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8873hi'>ASA8873hi</a></a>
```

Third Execution

```
<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8765jd'>ASA8765jd</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8765jd'>ASA8765jd</a></a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8765jd'>ASA8765jd</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8765jd'>ASA8765jd</a></a></a>
<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA7765jh'>ASA7765jh</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA7765jh'>ASA7765jh</a></a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA7765jh'>ASA7765jh</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA7765jh'>ASA7765jh</a></a></a>
<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8873hi'>ASA8873hi</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8873hi'>ASA8873hi</a></a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=<a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8873hi'>ASA8873hi</a>'><a href='http://www.stack.com=ASA8873hi'>ASA8873hi</a></a></a>
```

Comment: Why are you attempting multiple executions? Everyone answering here seems to be missing something.

Comment: This does not clarify at all why you are doing multiple executions. Also, please edit the links so that they do not show up as actual links. Place 4 spaces before each of the lines.

Comment: I tried to improve the question's formatting so that it would show the actual HTML (and not blue hyperlinked text) but it's too much work figuring out and writing what the Second and Third execution results should look like. @user803800, please do this yourself.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett - I  thought so too, until I realized I could just open up my favorite regex tool and run the original replacement three times. =]

Comment: My god, it grows exponentially!!

Comment: Yes! it grows at this fashion. So we can fix this problem only if the Pattern only matches plain text. This is the only way I think now. Is there any pattern that matches only plain text and leaves the rest untouched?

Comment: @thinkcool, your continued refusal to use global replacements while trying your hardest to implement your own inefficient clone (and your latest comment in particular) begs for Charles Babbage's famous quote, "I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."

Answer (score 2):

Why run it more than once though? `Global = True` means it replaces every occurrence of your regex in one `Replace` call.

Comment: Yes it replaces everything in a single click. But, if I change it to False, it replaces just the first pattern in the body and still have the same problem, when trying to do many executions.

Comment: OK... So why change it to false if you're trying to emulate `Global=True` anyway...

Comment: Your answer isn't a real answer, it's just a request for clarification!

Comment: Are you seriously that bored that you're necroing 3 year old threads to post.. that?

Answer (score 2):

Try some [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!http://www.stack.com=)ASA\d{4}[a-z]{2}(?!</a>)
```

(I took the liberty of shortening `[0-9]` to `\d` and using `{}` quantifiers.)

This will make sure that the string is not immediately following a link, nor is it followed by a hyperlink close tag. See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?2u22g).

You can add `\b` before and after the expression if you don't want to match the middle of words, such as in `xxASA8765jdxx`.

Comment: I tried this too...This does not work.It still replaces the entire hyperlink again

Comment: Then you've not given us the right example... What, exactly, are you trying?

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` to require the pattern to be at the beginning of the line:

```
.Pattern = "^ASA[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding word boundary flags to your regex:

`.Pattern = "\bASA[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z]\b"`

Comment: Ok, I know why it failed. What context will your match be appearing in? If it's always sitting on its own, you can specify the pattern surrounded by whitespace.